# Creating virtual directory in IIs for dnn website which uses new database

Tags: dotnetnuke

I want to create virtual directory for my dnn website which uses new database, for this I followed these steps.

go to iis server manager right click on site and click on add virtual directory

then I copied all file from dnn site to virtual directory folder and runs on browser it runs fine

after that I created new database and restore the backup of old database(which are used by Dnn website) on it . and change the connection string of virtual directory web.config file, it shows error "**Invalid login**" then I created new login in sql server and checked db_owner Properties of new database.

but when i browse site one issue occurring **"Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many redirects."**

so I want to know is these steps are right? if right then, how can i resolve this problem .

If any one have an idea please guide me

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to update the PORTALALIAS in the restored Database in order to get the site working. Your PortalAlias should match the URL of the virtual directory.

Comment: There are two connection strings in the web.config file, make sure that both of those strings are setup properly